# jupyter does not show all folders in my home directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I run my jupyter notebook, the home folder displayed in jupyter is always my home directory even if I start my notebook from a different directory. Also not all folders in my home  directory are displayed. I tried to change the access of the unshown folders by using chmod -R 0755 foldername, however the folders do not show when I run jupyter. 
I want all the folders in my home directory to show.

I am using ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I had some issue like this when i was running Jupyter Notebook over the Anaconda navigator. The issue was solved after i ran it over Anaconda prompt. Just run

```
jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score -2):

Open command promt,

pip
If you use pip, you can install it with:

### pip install notebook

Congratulations, you have installed Jupyter Notebook! To run the notebook, run the following command at the Terminal (Mac/Linux) or Command Prompt (Windows):

### jupyter notebook

Comment: The OP has already install Jupyter Notebook.  This does not answer the question.